# writing and reading numbers from text file using java

Tags: java, text

Basically I'm trying to write a program that will write 6 numbers at a time, keep adding to this file each time I save the numbers. After that I would like to read the text file, pick the numbers that come up more then a say 5 times or more (whatever I specify). 
Question is this I guess, if I read in each line as a string, will I still be able to step through each number to figure out which ones have been entered more then 5 or more times or would I have to read them one at a time as a char?

Comment: Please include some code to show what you have tried.

Comment: How are the number going to be saved? A number per line?

Comment: @delephin Each line 6 numbers if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can read lines as string and then covert that string to char array.

Here is example:

```
String line = "12345";
char[] charArray = line.toCharArray();
for(char ch : charArray)
{
     int nummber = (int)ch;
}
```

Comment: I haven't implemented anything yet.. I was just trying to figure out the best way to write/read the data so that I can later analyze each number individually. Hope this clarifies